# Why doesn't Sator use inversion to create redundant copies of the Algorithm?

Tags: tenet

In Tenet, it is possible to create multiple copies of an item (or person) via inversion: send it back in time, then forward, then back again, etc., so at any point in the middle there will be multiple copies (some traveling forward, some traveling back).

Why doesn't Sator take advantage of this to create multiple copies of the pieces of the Algorithm, to better safeguard them for the future?

Comment: There can be multiple copies at specific times, but if you wait long enough, there is only one copy left (because all the others would disappear through inversion)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're suggesting he could then bury multiple copies for the future people to dig up, that's not really how it works. There would only ever be one copy of the Algorithm that would make it to the future, because every time you invert something it doesn't continue on into the future. I'll try to explain with a text diagram:

> Past➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠➠Future
>  Un-inverted←←←←←←←←←←←←← Algorithm hidden and inverted
>  ↳→→→→→→→→→Inverted
>  Un-inverted←←←←←←↲
>  ↳→→→→→→→→→Inverted
>  Un-inverted←←←←←←↲
>  ↳→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→ Future antagonists get it

Sator wouldn't be able to take any of the copied Algorithms to send to the future because due to the closed-loop rules those pieces *must* ultimately be inverted to create the next copy. Every copy that gets made has to be inverted, except for the final "copy" which can continue into the future.